# c# Tree/MindMap GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface

i am trying to research some gui technology for c# where i can display a tree view (opposed to the standard one provided.)

Essentially i want to have the gui draw a tree of data (as if you were going to draw a binary tree on a piece of paper or something) Then making each of the nodes clickable.

If this isnt available does anyone know of something where i could have a mindmap type GUI which shows links between elements and those are clickable?

I can guess people will say make one yourself, in which case i give up already ;) thats too advanced for me and as i am on a work placement i dont think i would be granted the time to make it as there are more pressing issues to get working first, like actually making the programme work!

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a look at the controls in [Kevin's WPF Bag-o-Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) which has a WPF mind map style layout. [Here](http://www.iterature.com/dadameter/rrengine.php) is a nice example. If you want to use more professional components take a look at the product from [Nevron Software](http://www.nevron.com/Products.DiagramFor.NET.Overview.aspx), they have some great controls. There is also an opensource WPF graphing library - [graphsharp](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) (which I have no experience with, but I found a [nice article by Sacha Barber](http://sachabarber.net/?p=815)). Since it's used in nDepend it must be pretty mature.

I hope you get some inspiration from those links :)

Answer (score 1):

I also found XMind API for C#
https://xmindapi.codeplex.com/

It's free and looks easy to use.